# How to calculate the difference of a month of the current year and same month from previous year in SQL

Tags: sql

Let's say we have the following data:

Table Screenshot:

[image: Table Screenshot]

If I want to calculate the difference for Feb 2018 and Feb 2017, is it possible in SQL ?

Comment: What sql is it.. TSQL , PLSQL, MySQL. Please tag appropriately.. and show expected results.

Comment: What is your query?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a self join like shown below and provide where condition if necessary

```
SELECT CurrYear.MONTH,CurrYear.Yr,CurrYear.VAL-PrevYear.val as diff
FROM   #Table1 CurrYear INNER JOIN #Table1 PrevYear ON CurrYear.Yr = PrevYear.Yr-1 AND CurrYear.MONTH = PrevYear.MONTH
```